# Работа с БД в wpf с помощью EF Core

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, entity-framework-core

мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку число из textbox попадало в базу данных

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        Class Class1 = new Class { Num = Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text) };
        db.Classes.Add(Class1);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
public class Class
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Num { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilderoptionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source= (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Classs\r_sho\source\repos\DB\DB\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    }
}
```

при нажатии на кнопку в строке

```
Database.EnsureCreated();
```

появляется ошибка:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "An attempt to attach an
>   auto-named database for file
>   C:\Classs\r_sho\source\repos\DB\DB\Database1.mdf failed. A database
>   with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it
>   is located on UNC share."

Comment: Ну так бд уже существует, поэтому вы не можете ее ещё раз создать. Вам либо нужно удалять ее перед созданием, либо создавать только при отсутствии, а не безусловно.

Comment: Вы и прикрепляете и создаете БД, надо определиться, что вы хотите?